# Istio-Gateway automatically manage the IPs

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, kubernetes-ingress, istio

There is a pool of IP addresses of the external load balancer that were given to the Istio-Gateway.
When deploying there is a need to have a unique IP address selected for each deployment.

How can the IP address either be patched or enforced for each service or what should the Istio settings be for a external load balancer deployment in order to automatically manage the IPs?

Answer (score 0):

For `Loadbalancer` type service you can actually specify a IP address through `loadBalancerIP` parameter, but kubernetes itself doesn't support this feature. It works with some cloud providers. Actually, I quote from the docs:

> Some cloud providers allow you to specify the loadBalancerIP. In those
>   cases, the load-balancer is created with the user-specified
>   loadBalancerIP. If the loadBalancerIP field is not specified, the
>   loadBalancer is set up with an ephemeral IP address. If you specify a
>   loadBalancerIP but your cloud provider does not support the feature,
>   the loadbalancerIP field that you set is ignored.

On GKE it works. We have couple of clusters with Istio where we are forcing the IP address of `istio-ingressgateway` service.

Note that `istio-ingressgateway` is just a kubernetes service, so you have to treat it as that.